# Can't build gem5 on Manjaro Linux

Tags: python, scons, gem5

I have installed the python and base-devel packages necessary for building, but whenever I try to run scons with

```
python `which scons` build/X86/gem5.opt -j9
```

it gives me this error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Mkdir(".../gem5/build/X86/gem5.build")
Checking for linker -Wl,--as-needed support... yes
Checking for compiler -Wno-free-nonheap-object support... yes
Checking for compiler -gz support... yes
Checking for linker -gz support... yes
Info: Using Python config: python3-config
Checking for C header file Python.h... yes
Checking Python version... no
Error: Can't find a working Python installation
```

I'm at a loss at how to make scons detect my python installation

I have installed all the required packages, is it some incompatibility issue with arch?

Comment: So whatever this issue is, it's likely due to gem5's usage of SCons, and not something SCons does by default..  What's the path to your python? Which version of python? Which version of SCons?

Comment: SCons: v4.4.0. Python 3.11.3  By python path, you mean PYTHONPATH? I set it to /usr/bin/python but it still gives me the same error. I'm not sure if I need to set up any other environment variable

Comment: So, first off: you do have a working Python. SCons is written in Python and you would have gotten nowhere if Python itself wasn't working fine, so there's something the setup is looking for that isn't right.  Configure checks are part of the build config (that is, the Gem5 setup), and the remnants of what they tried are left in `.sconf_temp` - take a look if you can find the failing test there and see what it was looking for that failed. We should be able to make more comments on that, but maybe a Gem person will recognize something familiar

Comment: Looking at the SConstruct file, I found this part ```py_version = conf.CheckPythonLib()
        if not py_version:
            error("Can't find a working Python installation")``` inside a "with gem5_scons.Configure(env) as conf:". And the CheckPythonLib seems to be a method from "gem5/site_scons/gem5_scons/configure.py". I'm not sure which way would be best to post the contents here in a legible manner.

Comment: Generally, check the bug tracker of the software you're trying to install. For a question here, there's way too little info provided. Formally, you'd have to extract a [mcve] from the sources and also provide exact steps to reproduce the issue. I'd say, overall, your question isn't really suitable to SO. In any case, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

A link on github would be fine - located that myself. https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/b271367a357cbb390084884e809235d6d62b9cf5/site_scons/gem5_scons/configure.py#L100

From that, my first assumption would be that the dev package for `pybind11` is not installed, since that's what is uses for the check.  On Fedora, that's `pybind11-devel`. However, it looks like gem5 contains a vendored copy of that, so it's failing the build of the check program instead.

I see gem5 renames the configure droppings to its own preference (which is fine). If you look in `build/X86/gem5.build/config.log` you should see the evidence you need. I just tried it here, and it fails for me with what's clearly version skew with Python - I have Py 3.11 and there are tons of deprecation warnings (which may or may not be enough to fail the build) and some outright errors about missing members and incomplete types. Please check back with the gem5 project about any version requirements they may have listed.

Comment: I have looked at https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/building#dependencies and I don't see any missing dependency, at least from what's on the arch repositories. They have a bigger package list below for ubuntu, but I'm not sure what would be the equivalent for arch, which might be the cause of the build issue

Comment: it didn't look to me like the header files with pybind11 included with gem5 are compatible with the current version of Python, but that's not my area of expertise (I'm looking at it from the SCons veiwpoint).